# Why can't an Azure-DevOps user see other users?

Tags: azure-devops

I have an organization hosted in Dev.azure.com that contains two projects. In addition to myself, there are another two users, both of whom I have given Visual Studio Subscriber rights and made members of all of the same groups as I have membership to. One of these users is severely limited as to what work item properties he has access to. For example, the 'assigned' field is read only for him. He cannot assign a work item to another user. He can, however, change the status of the work item. Any idea why he is so limited in access and how might this be addressed? Could this be because his email address is not associated with an MSDN subscription?

I've tried going over the available Azure DevOps organization and project pages looking for every place I can find where rights may be assigned. In all cases I have attempted to make his memberships and so on look the same as mine.

The DevOps organization is a free membership because it has only three members associated with it.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi ,Are the answers provided below helpful?If you have any question,please kindly let me know.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like he has been degraded to Stakeholder, because Azure DevOps can't verify the Visual Studio Subscription (f.k.a MSDN subscription). Try giving him one of the 5 free basic licenses until he resolves the subscription association.

[image]

> https://my.visualstudio.com/subscriptions

Answer (score 1):

> For example, the 'assigned' field is read only for him. He cannot
>   assign a work item to another user.

For this sentence , does it refer to this is no identities found in the drop-down list of assigned field? Or is the assigned field completely unchangeable?

If it is the former, I can provide a solution, you can try it.

The solution is, rather than trying to select the team member from the drop-down list, type their full email address and hit the "Search" button. You can refer to this [case](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/55566/unable-to-assign-user-story-to-team-member.html).

If it's the latter, you'd better share a screenshot of the assigned field. Because through the test, I found that even if the access level is stakeholder and the permission is set to the project reader, the assigned field can still be modified.